# In SQL Server Management Studio\SQLCMD mode, can I use variables WITHIN a set of statements

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to make some of my setup scripts more readable and less prone to error.  Here's the type of code I have now in my SQLCMD scripts, which I run from management studio:

```
!!bcp "select * from Database1..Table1 where CreateDate > '7/11/2010'" queryout C:\junk\Table1.tab -n  -SServerName1 -UTestUser -PTestPassword
!!bcp "select * from Database1..Table2 where CreateDate > '7/11/2010'" queryout C:\junk\Table2.tab -n  -SServerName1 -UTestUser -PTestPassword
```

Instad of needing to hardcode the date in each statement, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
declare @Date1 datetime
select  @Date1 =  '7/11/2010'

!!bcp "select * from Database1..Table1 where CreateDate > @Date1" queryout C:\junk\BCPData\Table1.tab -n  -SServerName1 -UTestUser -PTestPassword
!!bcp "select * from Database1..Table2 where CreateDate > @Date1" queryout C:\junk\BCPData\Table2.tab -n  -SServerName1 -UTestUser -PTestPassword
```

Notice that in the second set of code, the date is no longer hardcoded.

Is there a way to do this, or are there good alternatives?

thanks for any ideas!
Sylvia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work? (Bit of a guess based on [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/))

```
:setvar date "7/11/2010"
!!bcp "select * from Database1..Table1 where CreateDate > '$(date)'" queryout C:\junk\Table1.tab -n  -SServerName1 -UTestUser -PTestPassword
!!bcp "select * from Database1..Table2 where CreateDate > '$(date)'" queryout C:\junk\Table2.tab -n  -SServerName1 -UTestUser -PTestPassword
```

**Edit**

Yep. The following works for me

```
:setvar date "07/07/2008"
!!bcp "select * from master.sys.objects where Create_Date > '$(date)'" queryout C:\master.tab -n  -S(local) -T
```

Comment: Thanks Martin!  This will make some of my scripts quite a bit more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you *can't* do this with DECLAREd SQL variables, however check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx) for guidance on using scripting variables within SQLCMD - which I would expect to apply to SQLCMD mode as well.